# WordPress не выводит данные с поля таксономии

Tags: php, html, wordpress, frontend, acf

Подскажите почему WP не выводит контент с поля таксономии
Использую вот такой код для вывода заголовка

```
<?=get_field('zagolovok',$product_category->term_id); ?>
```

ID проверял , id возвращается верный
но wp все равно ничего не выводит
Подскажите пожалуйста из за чего это происходит и как это исправить?
Во внутренней странице таксономии используется такой код

который возвращает все тот же id ... И там все работает

```
<?php
  $args = array(
      'taxonomy' => 'sbor_taxonomy',
      'orderby'    => 'count',
      'order'      => 'DESC',
      'hide_empty' => false
  );

  $product_categories = get_terms( $args );
  $i;
  $count = count($product_categories);
  if ( $count > 0 ){
      foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
          if($product_category->name != "Uncategorized"){
        $i++;
              ?>
                            <option value="<?=$product_category->name; ?>"></option>

              <div class="d5-item d5-item-<?=$i;?>">
                  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/static/imgs/d5.png"
                       alt="">
                  <div class="wrap">
                      <div class="program-item">
                          <h2><?=get_field('zagolovok',$product_category->term_id); ?></h2>

                          <h2><?=$product_category->name; ?></h2>
                          <h2><?=$product_category->term_id; ?></h2>

                          <p>
                                <?=get_field('kratkoe_opisanie', $product_category->term_id); ?>
                          </p>
                          <a href="<?=get_permalink();?>" class="standart-more">Сборы программы</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

          <?}                     }
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что нужно читать документацию. Вы тянете поле из поста, а у вас термин: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/

```
echo get_field( 'field1', 'term_' . $product_category->term_id );
```